# "броски кубиков" происходят бесконечно

Tags: javascript, event-loop

Этот код имитирует бросок 2 кубиков. В зависимости от того, что на них выпало, увеличивается height соответствующего блока. Таким образом хотел получить кривую распределения, задавая количество бросков через i в цикле. setInterval использовал, чтобы задать временной промежуток между бросками

```
var height2 = 0;
var height3 = 0;
var height4 = 0;
var height5 = 0;
var height6 = 0;
var height7 = 0;
var height8 = 0;
var height9 = 0;
var height10 = 0;
var height11 = 0;
var height12 = 0;

function startFunction() { 

  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var z = x+y;

  if (z==2) {  
  height2 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column2").style.height =  height2 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==3) {  
  height3 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column3").style.height =  height3 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==4) {  
  height4 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column4").style.height =  height4 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==5) {  
  height5 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column5").style.height =  height5 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==6) {  
  height6 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column6").style.height =  height6 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==7) {  
  height7 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column7").style.height =  height7 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==8) {  
  height8 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column8").style.height =  height8 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==9) {  
  height9 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column9").style.height =  height9 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==10) {  
  height10 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column10").style.height =  height10 + "px";
  }

  else if (z==11) {  
  height11 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column11").style.height =  height11 + "px";
  }

  else {  
  height12 += 0.1;
  document.getElementById("column12").style.height =  height12 + "px";
  };
  };

function cubesRandom () {
  for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    setInterval (startFunction, 1000);
  };
  };
```

Comment: "цикл длится бесконечно" - какой цикл? как Вы это выяснили? Зачем Вы запускаете одновременно пять одинаковых таймеров?

Comment: Во-первых, вместо `height2` ... `height12` должен быть массив, дабы не создавать такой ад из переменных и `else-if`-ов. Во-вторых, вы устанавливаете 5 интервалов (функций, которые будут постоянно вызываться через заданный интервал времени) и ни один из них не останавливаете - стоит ли удивляться тому, что код у вас выполняется бесконечно? И, вероятно, в 5 раз быстрее, чем вы планировали...

Comment: Опишите чего вы хотели добиться этим кодом.

Comment: Этот код имитирует бросок 2 кубиков. В зависимости от того, что на них выпало, увеличивается height соответствующего блока. Таким образом хотел получить кривую распределения, задавая количество бросков через i в цикле. setInterval использовал, чтобы задать временной промежуток между бросками

Comment: @Александр, перенеси это описание в сам вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы код выполнялся заданное количество раз с заданным промежутком временем между итерациями, можно действительно использовать функцию `setInterval`, но задавать стоит только один интервал, а также вовремя его останавливать с помощью функции `clearInterval`.

Также стоит отказаться от множества переменных высоты в пользу массива, либо вообще считать высоту элемента от текущей.

```js
function cubesRandom(count) {
  var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  var iteration = 0;
  var intervalId;
  
  function generateAndShowValue() {
    iteration++;
    if (iteration > count) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      return;
    }
    var first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var second = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var value = first + second;
    columns[value].style.height = (columns[value].clientHeight + 5) + "px";
  }
  
  intervalId = setInterval(generateAndShowValue, 10);
}

cubesRandom(300);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">2</div>
<div class="column">3</div>
<div class="column">4</div>
<div class="column">5</div>
<div class="column">6</div>
<div class="column">7</div>
<div class="column">8</div>
<div class="column">9</div>
<div class="column">10</div>
<div class="column">11</div>
<div class="column">12</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо! буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

```
function cubesRandom() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(startFunction, 500 * (i + 1));
  }
}

cubesRandom();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!